# They vs it when talking about companies

Tags: pronouns

X company offers the best coverage plans. **They** also offer great benefits.

X company offers the best coverage plans. **It** also offers great benefits.

Or

X is a known company in the world of tech. **They** make the best products.

X is a known company in the world of tech. **It** makes the best products.

Is using they to refer to a company a grammatically sound choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a similar question recently, on subject-verb agreement involving collective nouns.

Depending on region, some writers follow more the notional agreement, and some, the grammatical agreement.

Both ways are fine, but consistency is key.

I have observed that writers sometimes change their mind midway in a paragraph or even in a sentence.  This is undesirable.

> X company offers the best coverage plans. They also offer great benefits.

> X company offers the best coverage plans. It also offers great benefits.

> X is a known company in the world of tech. They make the best products.

> X is a known company in the world of tech. It makes the best products.

(2) and (4) are my preferred choices as consistency is followed.  Both examples use the singular for collective noun, i.e., they **consistently** follow their choice, in this case the grammatical agreement.

In (1) and (3), the writers change their mind from following grammatical agreement to notional agreement.

If we prefer to use plural for a company, we may write

> X company [**offer**] the best coverage plans.  They also offer great benefits.